# Multi-value fields in profiles - how to?

Tags: wordpress, profile, custom-fields

When I add a multi-value custom fields to a profile, Civi only allows visitors to enter the fields once - as a simple fields.

How to configure custom fields and profile to get form with multi-field table described in "Multi-value fields in profiles" section on http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/

This table with 'new record' in form is also described there http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Multiple-record+Custom+Data+Sets+in+Profiles

Comment: I noticed that multi-field profile with table and 'new record' button works only with 'edit mode" and logged users. Any ideas how to make it works with 'create mode' and public pages?

Comment: Duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9557/edit-multi-value-multi-record-fields-in-profiles?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20901/multi-value-fields-in-profile/26799#26799

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can add multiple values in multi-value field in create mode (out of the box) at the moment.

You could have the user fill in one value and have them add more later. If you don't want the user to have to login you could send them a [checksum token](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens).